# Receive: "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension" when trying to install rails gem on ruby 1.9.2 using pik

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, pik

I was trying to push my local database to Heroku and received this error:

`...Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range:...`

Some googling later I discovered that this error doesn't occur with `ruby 1.9.2` and that (because being on windows) I'd have to install `pik` to run 1.9.2 alongside 1.9.3. So I installed pik and ruby 1.9.2.

However, when I try to install `rails` on `1.9.2` I get this error:

`...ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension...`

After plenty of googling I've ran into the following:

- Don't bother using windows for ruby/rails development :(
- Something to do with devkit?
- Or installing a binary kit version of rails?
- Compile it yourself

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

Full error stack trace:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -
I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-par
entheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -O3 -Wall -O
0 -ggdb  -o generator.o -c generator.c
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Comment: The `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension` error message is specific to a gem; one of the many gems bundled within `rails` is failing to install. The fix would most likely be different for each `gem`. Best to identify which gem is causing the error. It would help if you paste the full error stack trace.

Comment: Hi Prakesh, I updated the post with the full error. Is it failing to install the json gem? Do I need to install the devkit for ruby 1.9.2 as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884267/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-install-json-on-windows-7. If so, how do I go about doing this? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the error message is `gcc: Command not found`; so the compiler is not available to compile the code locally.

If you already have `gcc` installed on your machine somewhere, make sure it is included in the `PATH`.

Check the [How to install gcc on windows 7 machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394755/how-to-install-gcc-on-windows-7-machine) for guidance on how to install gcc on windows.

Comment: Thanks for your help Prakesh :) For anyone who sees this post. I used the following guide to install gcc: [Getting Started | MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started)